# How to find the cosets of $H$ in $G.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> $G=\{\tau_{ab}:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R:x\mapsto ax+b|a\neq0\}$ is a group under composition of mapping and $H=\{\tau_{ab}\in G |a\in \mathbb Q\}\leq G.$ How to find the cosets of $H$ in $G.$

I have shown $H\tau_{ab}=H\tau_{cd}\iff \dfrac{a}{c}\in \mathbb Q.$

Comment: Assuming that your work so far is correct, you appear to have one coset of $H$ for each set $x\Bbb Q$ such that $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. In other words, your cosets of $H$ correspond to equivalence classes of $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ of the relation $x\sim y$ iff $x\in y\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Ya .. but how can I use it to list out the cosets?

Comment: If your characterization is correct $-$ I’ve not checked $-$ you can’t list them; you can only describe them, in the sense of being able to say simply when $\tau_{ab}$ and $\tau_{cd}$ are in the same coset.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Will {{$τ_{cd}\in G$:a/c∈Q}:a∈R\{0} } work?

Comment: You can say it more nicely: $$H\tau_{ab}=\{\tau_{cd}:c\in a\Bbb Q\}\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 2):

For non-zero $x,y\in\Bbb R$ define $x\sim y$ iff $\frac{x}y\in\Bbb Q$ iff $x\in y\Bbb Q$; $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, and $H\tau_{ab}=H\tau_{cd}$ iff $a\sim b$. The cosets of $H$ correspond to $\sim$-equivalence classes: $$H\tau_{ab}=\{\tau_{cd}:c\sim a\}=\{\tau_{cd}:c\in a\Bbb Q\}\;.$$